# Ошибка при срабатывании скрипта

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток! У меня вот какая проблема, все наверно знают плагин fancybox который при клике на картинку увеличивает её, так вот этот плагин я использую только один раз на сайте, вызываю я его через файл script.js вот таким образом:

```
$(function(){
    $("a[rel=fancybox]").fancybox({

    });
});
```

сам фал подключается на всех страницах так как там хранится много всяких скриптов.
Так вот если зайти на страницу где не используется данный плагин, в консоле вылазит вот такая ошибка 
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox' script.js:72
(anonymous function)
и соответственно некоторые скрипты данного фала не срабатывают.
Не хочу плодить много js файлов, как это исправить????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать проверку:

```
$(function(){
    if ($.fancybox) {
        $("a[rel=fancybox]").fancybox({

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! а как-то можно избежать этого в дальнейшем?? а то мне пришлось почти на все скрипты вешать проверку.

Comment: Ну это уже надо смотреть что и как вы написали.